# Strange Bug : List.append in Python erasing precedent input and cloning the new one instead each

Tags: python, list

Ok I have been working many times with list in python and it s the first time I encounter this problem :
Near the strange place I've got this ( simplified )

```
list = []
dict = {}
things = {'1':'Am', '2':'I', '3':'Dumb?'}
[...]

for key,value in things.items():
    if value:
        dict[key]=value

        print(dict)
        list.append(dict)
        print(list)
```

And get the this result :

```
{'1':'Am'}
[{'1':'Am'}]
{'2':'I'}
[{'2':'I'},{'2':'I'}]
{'3':'Dumb?'}
[{'3':'Dumb?'},{'3':'Dumb?'},{'3':'Dumb?'}]
```

hinhin, someone have ever get this ? I, m stuck, thank iou :)

Comment: Please don't use word ```list``` as a variable... it is a python keyword.

Comment: Also dict. It is also a keyword.

Comment: This is not strange, you simply append the *same* dictionary each time to the list.

Comment: I know it s just for simplification, as dict...but thx

Comment: Willem Van Onsem, but the tmp dict is changed at each iteration ( with key and value) , as shown in the print.

Comment: The code you have posted does not produce the output you've given. Could you update your question with the code you are running.

Comment: @Sid neither ̀`list` nor `dict` are keywords - if they were, trying to use them as variable names would raise a SyntaxError.

Comment: @pouardTintin the code snippet doesn't match the results so either one or the other is not the real thing. Please edit your post to fix this.

Comment: @Sid Are you sure you're not using another language ?-) (hint: you might be using an IDE with an integrated linter that issues a _warning_ about this, but I can assure you that it does NOT raise any error. FWIW, the exact list of Python keywords is documented: https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).

Comment: No, @brunodesthuilliers I just told @pouardtintin to not use ```list``` and ```dict``` because they are functions. Sorry, I accidentally said keyword, I meant function

Comment: Also I am definitely using python 

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* a bug. You simply add the *same* dictionary multiple times to the list. As a result if you manipulate that dictionary, you see the changes in all elements of the list, since these all refer to the *same* dictionary.

You should create a *new* dictionary each iteration, for example with:

```
result = []
things = {'1':'Am', '2':'I', '3':'Dumb?'}

for key, value in things.items():
    if value:
        result.append({key: value})
    print(list)
```

Or with simple list comprehension:

```
result = [{k: v} for k, v in things.items() if v]
```

Comment: OooooK got It ! thanx ;)

Comment: While this seems to solve the OP issue, I would like to point that the explanation doesn't match the OP's observed results.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers:I think it is very likely there is a `dict.clear()` somewhere in the `for` loop :) that is something the Occam's razor principle suggests :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem "In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess" ;-)